# Best free game server for an MMO developed in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

- What is the best free game server for a game developed in Flex 4?
- Is it possible to make the server using other programming languages?

Comment: Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Since you got no threads in ActionScript3 I doubt that developing game server in Flex is possible?

Comment: @fiction The original question did not ask for a game server developed in Flex.  I interpreted it as "What server should I use as the backend to a Flex Game."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex will integrate with any remote server of your choice.  What you want depends on what type of games you want to build.  If you just want a single player casual game, then any server will work for that.  .NET is the only server side platform I know that supports multiple languages.

If you want to create a multiplayer game, then you probably want to look into a media server.

[Red5](http://red5.org/) is an open source free option.  [Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) is an Adobe option, but I don't know if there is a free version.

GraniteDS is similar to BlazeDS and/or LiveCycle.  It supports server side push, so the server can push data to the client.

Also, for more resources on developing Flash Platform Games, check out [Adobe's Resource Center for game development](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games.html).

Answer (score 3):

The server should not be developed using Flex 4, it's not made for..

Take a look at BlazeDS for Flex interactions.

Comment: Agree.
To be honnest, I'm also wondering why the game is developped with Flex.
Flex is definately not aimed at developing games